# Javascript Prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I am reading Javascript Web Applications by Alex Maccaw. Below is a snippet where a Class constructor is built.

```
    var Class = function(parent){
        var klass = function(){
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
     };

  // Change klass' prototype 
    if (parent) {
        var subclass = function() { };
        subclass.prototype = parent.prototype;
        klass.prototype = new subclass;
    };

  klass.prototype.init = function(){};

  // Shortcuts
  klass.fn = klass.prototype;
  klass.fn.parent = klass;
  klass._super = klass.__proto__;      

  /* include/extend code... */

  return klass;
};
```

The abit i'm interested in is

```
    var subclass = function() { };
    subclass.prototype = parent.prototype;
    klass.prototype = new subclass;
```

Why doesn't he go

```
    klass.prototype = parent.prototype;
```

He explains it: "This little dance around creating a temporary anonymous function prevents instances from being created when a class is inherited". This still doesn't make sense to me, how would

```
    klass.prototype = parent.prototype;
```

make instances be created?

Comment: As cookie pointed out its not a good idea to create intace of Parent to set prototype part of inheritance maybe the following answer can help understanding the behavior of prototype. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because then anything you put on `klass.prototype` would also go on `parent.prototype` since they're the same object.

What he's doing is making a new object that *inherits* from `parent.prototype`, and assigning that object to `klass.prototype`, so that any properties added to it, don't get put on `parent.prototype`.

---

FYI, a more modern way to do that would be to use `Object.create()`

```
klass.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
```

This accomplishes basically the same thing.

---

This sentence you pointed out:

> *" "This little dance around creating a temporary anonymous function prevents instances from being created when a class is inherited""*

...is an odd way to explain it, unless there's a greater context where it makes sense. Perhaps he means to say that you don't need to invoke the `parent` constructor in order to obtain an object that inherits from `parent.prototype`.

If you did this:

```
klass.prototype = new parent();
```

It would accomplish the same thing, except that the `parent` constructor would be invoked, and there could be undesired side effects in doing so.